# Camera programatically not open in OnePlus 3 Android Phone Os v 6.2

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent, android-camera2

When  try to open camera in OnePlus 3 mobile phone its crash please let me know how can i fix this issue. following code using ..

```
    File tempFile = createFile();
    if (intentCamera.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) 
     {
            if (tempFile != null) 
             {

                mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(tempFile);

                intentCamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
                intentCamera.putExtra("return-data", true);
                startActivityForResult(intentCamera, ConstantString.REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PICTURE);
            }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove following line

`intentCamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
intentCamera.putExtra("return-data", true);`

No need to pass Extras while launching camera intent.

```
File tempFile = createFile();
    if (intentCamera.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) 
     {
            if (tempFile != null) 
             {

                mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(tempFile);
                startActivityForResult(intentCamera, ConstantString.REQUEST_CODE_TAKE_PICTURE);
            }
      }
```

Comment: Then how can receive result onActivityResult?